# Does YouTube's API allow uploading and setting of thumbnails?

Tags: python, api, youtube

I haven't found anything in their documentation or on the web that says yes or no.  Using the Python library.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently thumbnails can't be *updated*, per [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Updating_Video_Entry) -- [media:thumbnail](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_media:thumbnail) is not listed among the tags you can set on update. On *uploading* the video, yes, you can have `media:thumbnail` tags as part of your `media:group` tag which gives the video's metadata.

Comment: While technically true that it can be set, I've found in practice that setting the thumbnail tag does not effectively set the thumbnail for a video on the initial upload.